# Why can't I enter connection string for blob storage account in my azure function configuration?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions

After I created an azure function app in the portal, I tried to create new function by choosing "BlobTrigger - C#" from the available templates and configure blob path and storage account connection string. While I can enter blob path, the text field for storage account is disabled. What am I missing?

Thanks.
Raghu/..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click the `+new` button to the right of the textbox to pick either an existing storage or create a new one.

[image: Storage Picker]